# Что делать с SEO в SPA приложении?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, seo, spa, ember.js

На текущий момент есть блог в виде Rails приложения. Страницы проиндексированы поисковиками.

В качестве дальнейшего развития проекта и моего личного обучения было написано приложение на Ember, в котором все маршруты Rails приложения были сохранены.

Разработка подходит к концу, хочется уже сделать релиз, но момент с SEO (заголовок страницы, meta теги и т.д.) меня очень сильно пугает. Читал, мол, Google умеет работать с SPA, но также читал - что умеет плохо. Про Yandex и др. я вообще без понятия.

Пробовал сделать с помощью FastBoot, но если в development среде что-то и было похожее на правду (страница отдавалась целиком, после получения ответа от API), то в production (хостинг и деплой - firebase), все было максимально динамически (списки появлялись по возможности, заголовок страницы менялся после получения ответа от сервера и прочее подобное).

Пожалуйста, подскажите решение данной проблемы. Для меня это очень больной вопрос, и я, к сожалению, не понимаю как его решить.

---

*P.S. Насколько я понимаю Ember имеет меньшее сообщество чем, например, Vue, поэтому, с вашего позволения, я укажу в вопросе еще и тег Vue, так как предполагаю что вопрос и его решение схожи.*

Comment: на практике гугл ничего не умеет, с эмбером не сталкивался, но так как это платформа схожая на `angular` - вам поможет только серверный рендеринг, как например в `linkedin`, приложение полностью написано на `ember.js`, но сервер отдает уже отрендеренную страницу, в вопросе с динамическими данными - тут вам поможет поиск в гугле с ключевыми словами `load data before render`, во многих фреймворках это называется `resolving`, но я думаю, что в `ember` немного другая философия

Comment: FastBoot при правильном использовании должен работать и на production. Вы скорее всего просто не смогли его там настроить.

Comment: @hindmost согласен. Возможно я сделал то-то не так. Читал гугл и доки после написания вопросов по fastboot, firebase и emder деплою, но так и не смог найти чего-то внятного. Плюс ко всему еще и про expressjs иногда пишут, что для меня вообще каким-то бредом кажется.

Comment: @overthesanity если говорить про SSR, то я не могу понять как то добро деплоить, ибо, например, если говорить про Ember, то многие приписывают expressjs, что меня в ступор ставит. И в то же время не вижу решения без того жу expressjs. Когда начинал познавать мир SPA, то не думал про SEO, но сейчас... после такого объема работы...

Comment: @Colibri, вам подойдет любой nodejs фреймворк, express/koa/hapi, это не столь важно, важный факт - да, без ноды вам не обойтись. хотел поинтересоваться почему вы выбрали именно ember? сколько уже работаю - ни  разу в наших краях не видел проекта на этой платформе :-) я думаю вам было бы гораздо проще взять react / vue, к тому же там есть прекрасные инструменты для SSR (next / nuxt), и морок у вас не было бы с деплоем

Comment: @overthesanity дело в том, что с Vue и его семейством я знаком давно, и даже реализовывал на нем несколько проектов. Как SPA без надобности в SEO и как компоненты в Rails (Webpacker). Но это отдельная и долгая история :) (Next и Nuxt это не то что мне нужно) А вот с Ember работаю с недавних пор, это была любовь с первого взгляда. Он держит в определенных рамках, да и разработка с ним намного приятнее и быстрее. имхо

Comment: @overthesanity но я вот сижу уже сутки над вопросом и знаете... Не раз мелькая мысль, мол, "а ну его на фиг, давай Rails + Vue компоненты где нужна динамика". SPA сводит с ума...

Comment: @Colibri, ну делайте как вам удобней, если нужно spa + ssr на одном из фреймворков, то это только нода :-)

Comment: @overthesanity SPA это по-своему красиво и интересно, но вопрос с SEO... Вроде бы мы с вами все обсудили, проблемы ясны, но это какой-то геморрой. И назревает вопрос по типу "оно вообще надо?". Вот писать админки с помощью Vue или Ember - супер. Но простые сайты...

Comment: @Colibri, я не соглашусь по поводу геморроя, но я, к сожалению, не знаю как это работает в эмбере, в `react / vue / angular` SSR поднимается несколькими строчками кода (на ноде естественно), используя готовые пакеты от команд, которые разрабатывают эти платформы и библиотеки

Comment: @overthesanity попробую тогда подойти к этому вопросу со стороны Vue.js, а то на текущий момент SSR в Ember мне до сих пор не дается, даже уже начал и Express ковырять...

Comment: @Colibri, вам не увильнуться от ноды :-) к тому чисто из любопытства посмотрел `quick start` на оф. сайте фастбута, вроде не так все сложно, но как говорится без труда....

Comment: @overthesanity да. У них на сайте все вообще идеально с первого взгляда. Но когда дело доходит до практики... Я честно пока до сих пор не понял как это связать (Ember и Express), так еще и деплоить надо (Dokku). И большой вопрос вокруг этого - сборка. Короче, темный лес...

Comment: @Colibri, крепитесь :-))